# How do you get a string from Django PostgreSQL ArrayField?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

I'm trying to get a string out of an ArrayField in my database but it only prints by characters, not the full string. For example, the ArrayField is named `words` and in the database it shows as `{word1, word2, word3}` so in the HTML I put `{{ object.words.0 }}` and `{` is rendered on the screen.

How can I get it to render `word1`?

I have added `django.contrib.postgres` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.
This is what it looks like in my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class WordArr(models.Model):
     words = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True))
```

Comment: How did you save the data? How are you sending the object to the view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have a CreateView that takes input from the user and creates an array, then makes the ArrayField equal to that.  I have a DetailView where I'm trying to access the object

Comment: You should *show that code*. Both views.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue and it was with my database.  The ArrayField in my model was previously a CharField that I changed.  I thought the migrations were correct however the database was still reading it as a CharField, so the output was the first character of a string.  I migrated to a new database and everything worked fine.  My code is below for further reference:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

# Create your models here.
class Word(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    words = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import Word

# Create your views here.
class ArrayCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Word
    fields = ['first', 'last']
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        w = form.save(commit=False)
        random_words = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
        w.words = random_words

        return super().form_valid(form)

class ArrayDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Word
```

**word_form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create Array</h1>
    <div>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**word_detail.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ object.words.0 }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
     'django.contrib.postgres',
     'arr',
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from arr.views import ArrayCreateView, ArrayDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('create/new/', ArrayCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', ArrayDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
]
```